# Error when import a function from a py file in other directory

Tags: python

I have a directory like

```
 .
    └── my_project
        ├── API
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── admin.py
        └── my_project
            ├── __init__.py
            └── module1_file.py
```

Inside API/admin.py, I want to import func1 from my_project/module1_file.py. I do like this:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, './myproject/myproject/')

from module1_file import func1
```

It throws me this error

```
       from module1_file import func1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1_file'
```

Can anyone please show me how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: It should be `sys.path.insert(0, '../myproject/')`

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, and I had tried using the full path.

Comment: What if you remove the `sys.path` line and try `from ..my_project.module1_file import func1`? Does that work? Python error messages aren't too informative so it may not be able to parse module1_file because there is an error in that file. You could also try running `module1_file` to see if that works

Comment: Why do you add `myproject/myproject` if you have folders with `_` - `my_project/my_project` ? `sys.path.insert(0, '/full/path/my_project/my_project/')` ?

Comment: @mattyx17 I will throw "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Comment: @furas sorry dude, would you be able to elaborate what you meant to say?

Comment: in project structure you have folder `my_project` (with `_`) but in code you use name `myproject` (without `_`) - and it is not the same folder. You have to use `my_project` in code.

Comment: @furas wow, good catch. It solved part of my problem, thanks. If I run `import module1_file`, python will recognise it; but when I call `module1_file.func1()`, or try  `from module1_file import func1`, it will throw me error `ImportError: cannot import name 'func1' from 'module1_file' `.

Comment: if it can't import `func1` then check if you really have `func1` in `module1_file`. Maybe you don't have it or it has little different name.